# trim() not working while applying to a string from a backbone model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm getting a string `"hi\nbye\ngoodluck\n\n{{optout}}"` from a backbone model. But i need to trim() the string. But it's not working.

When i'm using the same string with trim() in browser, it's working fine : `"hi\nbye\ngoodluck\n\n{{optout}}".trim()`

Expected output :

```
hi
bye
goodluck

{{optout}}
```

Comment: Neither string has whitespaces characters (whitespace, tab or newline) at the beginning or the end. `trim` removes those characters, so in your case it is not doing anything

Comment: your string has new lines not spaces(leading or trailing), that's why `trim()` doing nothing

Comment: @OscarPaz Can you just try in your browser console "hi\nbye\ngoodluck\n\n{{optout}}".trim(). You can see \n being converted into new line. I need that.

Comment: If you remove the `trim` it works as well. Your isseu has nothing to do with `trim`. What you want, I assume, is to see the string in differente lines? Where? in the console? In the page?

Comment: @OscarPaz Yes, I want to see the string in different lines and i want to see in the page.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. As it stands, it's impossible to answer since we don't have the exact value you're dealing with (the one from the model).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your string has `multiple-new-lines(\n)`,and `trim()` remove single new-lines. That's why issue occur

You need to use `.replace()` with a `pattern`

Working snippet:-

```js
console.log("hi\nbye\ngoodluck\n\n{{optout}}".replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n'));
```

Comment: it's working in console but not working while getting the same string from a backbone model.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with `trim`. `trim` does not convert ' \n' into a new line. '\n' is already a new line character. If you want to see the string in the page and in different lines, you must know that HTML ignores new lines, except if the text is inside `<pre>` tags.

You need to convert the newlines to a `<br>` tag before adding it to the page:

```js
var str = "hi\nbye\ngoodluck\n\n{{optout}}";

var convertedStr = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

 console.log(convertedStr);
```